# Problem compiling Platform SDK program

Tags: c++, windows, driver, platform-sdk

I'm trying to compile the example from here;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682619(VS.85).aspx

I've installed the Platform SDK, but I'm getting these errors;

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetDeviceDriverBaseNameW@12 referenced in function _main DriverChecker.obj   DriverChecker
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EnumDeviceDrivers@12 referenced in function _main    DriverChecker.obj   DriverChecker
Error   3   fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals C:\Files\Projects\VS2008\DriverChecker\Debug\DriverChecker.exe  DriverChecker
```

Anyone any idea how to get this compiling correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `psapi.lib` as an additional library in your linker options.

Edit properties for your project, navigate to Linker->Input, and type `"psapi.lib"` where it says Additional Dependencies.